# Is it possible to block an email/sms by android programmatically?

Tags: android, email, sms, android-4.4-kitkat, android-broadcastreceiver

I have schedule to make an android application which used to block spam emails (chosen by myself). However, I cannot find any way to do it. Is it possible to block/reject the email using android programmatically?

In addition, I found that from [KitKat version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587668/is-there-any-way-to-block-sms-programmatically-in-android-kitkat), we will not block a SMS by android programmatically. That means that we can not make an application for blocking the SMS. Is it right?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Note:Its just about `sms` not `email.`

You can block but in `KitKat and greator` but there is one condition your app should be default messaging app.

To Check default app

```
         if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                final String myPackageName = context.getPackageName();
                if (Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context).equals(
                        myPackageName)) {
                    flagToCheckForBlock = true;
                    abortBroadcast();
                }
            } else {
                flagToCheckForBlock = true;
                abortBroadcast();
            }
```

Comment: How about email? A default messaging app means I will receive message in that app, and the sms app of android will not show any mess. is it right?

Comment: This isn't really correct. The `abortBroadcast()` method is useless in a default app. Not even the default can abort the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast, and therefore cannot prevent other apps from receiving messages, if they're listening for them. Also, the default listens for a different broadcast to handle incoming messages, anyway.